# The superword-mode does not work in rst-mode buffer - what to look for?

Tags: rst-mode

For a reason I don't yet understand, `superword-mode` does not work in the `rst-mode` buffers in my Emacs.  I tried Emacs 26.3 and 27.2.

The `superword-mode` works fine in other major modes such as `text-mode`.

By not *not working* I mean: point stops at the underscore character in `something_like_this` instead of moving at the end when executing the **forward-word** command.

For example:  inside a a buffer holding the content of `afile.rst`, the content is the following:

```
This is a test for superword-mode.
Put point at_the_beginning_of_this_long_word inside this sentence.
By typing M-f it should move to the end, just after 'word' before ' inside'.
```

- The major mode of the buffer is `rst-mode`.
- Activate superword-mode with `M-x superword-mode`
- Place point on line 2, character 10, just before `at_the_beginning_of_this_long_word`
- Execute `forward-word`, normally bound to `M-f`
- In *superword-mode* working properly, point should move forward by 34 character just after the 'd' of 'word'

  - That's what it does in **text-mode**
  - But in **rst-mode**, point moves forward by 2 characters only, just after the word 'at'.

    - The `forward-mode` command behaves just as if `superword-mode` was not active, stopping at the underscore.
    - But looking at the value of the `superword-mode` variable in the *scope* of that buffer, I see that it is buffer-local set to `t`.
    - Inside the `afile.rst` buffer the superword-mode lighter is shown as expected.

Is there something that is known to interfere with `superword-mode` or some other known reason for it to not behave as expected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is likely due to the difference in the syntax class of an underscore (`_`) between `rst-mode` and `text-mode`.

With your cursor on the underscore, use `C-u C-x =` to see what syntax class is assigned to that char in each of the modes.

(In `text-mode` it has syntax `symbol`, by default. In `rst-mode` it appears to have `punctuation` syntax.)

If `superword-mode` requires an underscore to have a particular syntax class (e.g. `symbol`) for it to work properly, then you'll likely have to change its syntax class in `rst-mode` to get `superword-mode` to treat it properly. You can do that this way:

```lisp
(modify-syntax-entry ?_ "_" rst-mode-syntax-table)
```

But that might have other, negative effects in `rst-mode` - it's likely that `rst-mode` didn't assign an underscore char that syntax class on purpose. You might want to check other `rst-mode` buffers, to see if their content depends on `_` having punctuation syntax instead of symbol syntax.